# Spring with Neo4j - annotation configuration

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I try to set up my new project using Spring with Neo4j.

Here is my MainAppConfiguration.java:

```
package com.nutrilizer.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import com.nutrilizer.app.TestClass;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:/properties/database.properties")
public class MainAppConfig {

    @Autowired Environment env;

    @Bean
    public TestClass testClass() {
        return new TestClass(env.getProperty("db.location"));
    }
}
```

Neo4jConfig.java

```
package com.nutrilizer.configuration;

//imports here

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages="com.nutrilizer.repository")
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Autowired Environment env;

    @Autowired GraphDatabase graphDatabase;

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(env.getProperty("db.location"));
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate() {
        return new Neo4jTemplate(graphDatabaseService());
    }

    @Bean
    public GraphRepositoryFactory graphRepositoryFactory() {
        return new GraphRepositoryFactory(neo4jTemplate(), neo4jMappingContext());
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext() {
        return new Neo4jMappingContext();
    }
}
```

configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nutrilizer.configuration" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

When I try to run this code I get message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jConfig' defined in file [/home/mateusz-b/workspace/nutrilizer/target/classes/com/nutrilizer/configuration/Neo4jConfig.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.nutrilizer.configuration.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d313133] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.nutrilizer.configuration.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d313133] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:928)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.nutrilizer.app.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.nutrilizer.configuration.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d313133] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:923)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/validation/Validator;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:327)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.Validator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 19 more
```

I don't have any idea why it doesn't work. Can you tell me what's wrong with this configuration? Have you any solutions?

Comment: I've found solution. In pom.xml there wasn't dependency with javax.validation